# Angular Primeng Menubar Access To Method Problem

Tags: angular, frontend, angular8, primeng, menubar

I'm trying to call a method on the menu onclick event as follows, but it gives an error.

component.ts

```
    loadWorkSpace(WorkSpaceName: string, QNameSpaceId: number, QEnvironemntId: number, QWorkSpaceId: number) {
this._qWorkSpaceFilterServiceProxy
                    .getAll(QWorkSpaceId, null, 0, 1000)
                    .subscribe((result) => {
                        filterItemList = _map(result.items, function (qWSFilter) {
                            return {
                                label: qWSFilter.qWorkSpaceFilter.workspaceFilterName, command: (event: Event) => this.consoleMsg()
                            };
                        });

                        this.items = [
                            {
                                label: 'Applications',
                                items: itemList
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'Filters',
                                items: filterItemList
                            }
                        ];
                    });}

    consoleMsg() {
        console.log("test");
    }
```

Error:
[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4XWR.png)

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: the error shows us that your consoleMsg function will not be recognized.  the problem is not about your code snippet that is pasted here.

Comment: follow consoleMsg function and check its import / export statement. your problem can be solved easily with these few steps that I mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble accessing the 'this' token because of the '_map' method I used.

Doing it this way fixed it:

```
filterItemList = result.items.map((qWSFilter) => {
                            return {
                                label: qWSFilter.qWorkSpaceFilter.workspaceFilterName, command: (event) => { this.consoleMsg() }
                            };
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because consoleMsg() is not present at the time of call inside the function, just because consoleMsg() is described after the function call. You can try describing the consoleMsg() first and then the larger function.

Comment: I tried what you said but sorry it didn't work. Thank you for your answer.